# Few ways to promote islam.se that I am using

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I would like to highlight 2 ways I am using to promote this site, and get friends on it. Many people are unaware and we need to show the usefulness of this site.

1. I am using a stackapp - [stacktack](https://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere) which is a small widget that we can place on other sites where it is possible to like blogs.
   You can see it in action on [my site page](http://mdtareque.in/islam/islam-se.html), where I am displaying few of the hand-chosen post. All you need to do is include few lines of code, and give the question id which you see in the url. If anyone is not from a programming background, I can help you out with this. We can start a chat on this if required.
2. On any main question page of islam.se, on the right side you can see the following link to  subscribe for a weekly newsletter.
   This gives a summary of popular, quality, high voted questions and answer. I forward this mail to my other friends. This is a quite a good way to let people know, what all kinds of discussion is possible and also they get to know the proper authentic answers with references.

[image: newletter]

Hope, you also start using above ways to promote the site. This will be effective. Feedback is welcome.